# Azure cloud service/role instance stuck

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-role-environment

I have 4 instances of my cloud service and randomly one of instance gets stuck while initializing and i get the following error in portal dashboard

```
Busy (Waiting for role to start... Application startup tasks are running.Last role error: exit code - -2147467259, exit time - Last startup task error: name - "E:\plugins\RemoteAccess\RemoteAccessAgent.exe" /b)
```

Any reason why it gets stuck intermittently ?

Comment: Have u tried recycling the instance and stopping and starting service again

Comment: Yes, that fixes the problem. But this thing is happening quite frequent. Just want to fix the root cause rather than have a workaround of recycling the instance.

Comment: This may help you track down the culprit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/10/03/troubleshooting-scenario-7-role-recycling.aspx

Comment: Have you tries IntelliTrace http://www.bandgap.cs.rice.edu/classes/comp410/resources/Using%20Azure/WAPTK/Labs/WindowsAzureDebugging/Lab.html/html/docSet_bc54bb30-2da9-4acc-aaee-2dd83ded82f3.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to spin up 1 more instance. The application was caped out on the the memory.